# Fastest method to achieve this output matching using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range with several series of dates and values

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

And i need this output, a series of dates ( using the min date and max date from input ).

If output date matches with the input date of a series then set the value of this day if not set a 0. I have tried all kind of loops but i have 40 series o dates and values ( 80 columns x 2000 rows ) and i can't get anything fast.

[image]

Comment: Did you start by reading the data into a Variant array? See [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Yes i di @BigBen, i read the whole range aand put the data into a variant, but i'm always using nested loops to compare dates, it is really slow

Comment: Probably could use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to store the max and min. Perhaps best to [edit] your question with actual code you've tried.

Comment: I can generate the output date series without any problem using the min max date from input but the problem comes when triying to set the values for each date, no way to get something fast

Comment: As suggested, I'd use a `Scripting.Dictionary` (or two) - should be fast.

Comment: This is probably also doable in Power Query.

Comment: Many thanks @BigBen i am triying with dictionaries and see if improves

Comment: Are all dates 'series' sorted, as we can see in your picture? Is there some logic to be followed in order to identify the next series? Are they in consecutive pairs of columns? I mean the next series should be E:F, G:H and dates should be found in odd columns? It is important to know where from to be extracted the max/min `Dates`.

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru, all dates are sorted, oldest to newest, values are completly random. Yes, pair of columns are always consecutive like in your example. The min max date are extracted from date1, date2, date3

Comment: Are there only unique dates in one date series?

Comment: Yes @FaneDuru, only unique dates in each series of dates. many thanks

Comment: Do all series have the same number of rows?

Comment: I would suggest the next scenario: Search for min and max dates in columns keeping dates, then build an array of all dates between the two limits (directly in memory) (arr1). clone it and `Redim Preserve` in order to  add as many 'valuex' columns exist, calculating their number (arr2). It is allowed for the second dimension (columns). Then, place all existing (used) range in a big array (arr3) and iterate by rows. Iterate each row by columns, match the date of the odd columns in first array and fill the appropriate date in the appropriate row/column of second one.

Comment: Many thanks @FaneDuru, i am going to try your approach, by the way all series have not the same number of rows

Comment: OK. This will only change the way of last row calculation and skipping the empty array elements to be processed. I will also try making a piece of code. Not right now, since I have something to finish, but after that, if I will have some available time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. You must take care that the format in the analyzed range to be the same as the one in the built range (`dd/mm/yyyy`). It returns the processed array in another sheet (`sh1`). I used the next sheet. If it is empty in your case, you can use the code as it is. There must not exist other records in the first row, except the last `Valuex`. The code can be adapted to search this header type, but it is not the object of the solution:

```
Sub CentralizeDateValues()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngD As Range, lastCol As Long, lastColL As String
  Dim arrD1, arrD2, arrGen, minD As Date, maxD As Date, i As Long, j As Long
  Dim arrOddCols, arrCols, strCols As String, NoD As Long, mtch, col As Long, StartTime As Date
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set sh1 = sh.Next 'use here the sheet you need (where to return the processed range)
  
  lastR = sh.UsedRange.rows.Count                                        'last row
  lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'last column
  'extract the odd columns number in an array:
  arrOddCols = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & lastCol / 2 & ")*2-1)")
  Debug.Print Join(arrOddCols, "|"):     'just to visually check it. Comment the line after understanding what the above line does

  'obtain the columns letters array:
  ReDim arrCols(1 To UBound(arrOddCols))
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrOddCols)
        arrCols(i) = Split(cells(1, arrOddCols(i)).Address, "$")(1)
    Next i
  strCols = Join(arrCols, "1,") & "1": Debug.Print strCols        'just to visually check it.
  Set rngD = Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Range(strCols).EntireColumn) ' build the range where to match max/min dates
  
 minD = WorksheetFunction.min(rngD)
 maxD = WorksheetFunction.Max(rngD)
 NoD = maxD - minD + 1 'number the days in the range betweenthe min and max dates
 'build a continuous date array from min to max:
 arrD1 = Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(" & Year(minD) & "," & month(minD) & ",row(" & Day(minD) & ":" & NoD & ")),""dd/mm/yyyy"")")
 Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arrD1), "|")               'just to visually check it.
 
 arrD2 = arrD1   'clone the built dates array
 ReDim Preserve arrD2(1 To UBound(arrD1), 1 To UBound(arrCols) + 1) 'add the necessary columns for Values
 
 StartTime = Timer 'start the timer to count the time spent by the following code.

 arrGen = sh.Range("A2", sh.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value: col = 1
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrGen)
     For j = 1 To UBound(arrGen, 2) - 1 Step 2 'iterate from two to two columns to check dates (as string) and extract values
        If arrGen(i, j) <> "" Then
            col = col + 1
            mtch = Application.match(CStr(arrGen(i, j)), arrD1, True)
            If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
                arrD2(mtch, col) = arrGen(i, j + 1)
            Else
               arrD2(mtch, col) = "strange..." 'the code reaches this line only if a mistake is in the Dates range...
            End If
        End If
     Next j
     col = 1 'reinitialize the variable to set the column where the value to be placed
 Next i
 'drop the processed array content at once
 sh1.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrD2), UBound(arrD2, 2)).Value = arrD2
 Sub CentralizeDateLongValues()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngD As Range, lastCol As Long, lastColL As String
  Dim arrD1, arrD2, arrGen, minD As Date, maxD As Date, i As Long, j As Long
  Dim arrOddCols, arrCols, strCols As String, NoD As Long, mtch, col As Long, StartTime As Date
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set sh1 = sh.Next 'use here the sheet you need (where to return the processed range)
  
  lastR = sh.UsedRange.rows.Count                                        'last row
  lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'last column
  'extract the odd columns number in an array:
  arrOddCols = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & lastCol / 2 & ")*2-1)")
  Debug.Print Join(arrOddCols, "|"):     'just to visually check it. Comment the line after understanding what the above line does

  'obtain the columns letters array:
  ReDim arrCols(1 To UBound(arrOddCols))
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrOddCols)
        arrCols(i) = Split(cells(1, arrOddCols(i)).Address, "$")(1)
    Next i
  strCols = Join(arrCols, "1,") & "1": Debug.Print strCols        'just to visually check it.
  Set rngD = Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Range(strCols).EntireColumn) ' build the range where to match max/min dates
  
 minD = WorksheetFunction.min(rngD)
 maxD = WorksheetFunction.Max(rngD)
 NoD = maxD - minD + 1 'number the days in the range betweenthe min and max dates
   'build a continuous date array from long numbers, corespondent to min and max dates:
  arrD1 = Evaluate("row(" & CLng(minD) & ":" & CLng(maxD) & ")")
  'Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arrD1), "|"): 'Stop

 arrD2 = arrD1   ''clone the built dates arary
 ReDim Preserve arrD2(1 To UBound(arrD1), 1 To UBound(arrCols) + 1) 'add the necessary columns for Values
 
 StartTime = Timer 'start the timer to count the time spent by the following code.
 
 arrGen = sh.Range("A2", sh.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value2: col = 1
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrGen)
     For j = 1 To UBound(arrGen, 2) - 1 Step 2 'iterate from two to two columns to check dates (as string) and extract values
        If arrGen(i, j) <> "" Then
            col = col + 1
            mtch = Application.match(arrGen(i, j), arrD1, True)
            If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
                arrD2(mtch, col) = arrGen(i, j + 1)
            Else
               arrD2(mtch, col) = "strange..." 'the code reaches this line only if a mistake is in the Dates range...
            End If
        End If
     Next j
     col = 1 'reinitialize the variable to set the column where the value to be placed
 Next i
 'drop the processed array content at once
 With sh1.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrD2), UBound(arrD2, 2))
    .Value2 = arrD2
    .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
 End With
 'put headers:
 Dim arrHd: arrHd = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arrD2, 2) - 1 & ")"))
 arrHd = Split("Date|Value" & Join(arrHd, "|Value"), "|")
 sh1.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrHd) + 1).Value = arrHd: sh1.Activate
 MsgBox "Ready..." & vbCrLf & _
             " (" & Format(Timer - StartTime, "00.00") & " seconds)"
End Sub
End Sub
```

It returns in "A1" of the next sheet the header and in "A2" the processed array.

Please, send some feedback after testing it. I am curious how much it takes for a big range. I tested it on a small range, but solution must run on any range...

**Edited**:

Please, test the following version. It uses a `Long` numbers array, corresponding to the necessary Dates range. This allows using `value2` to create the global array, which allows a (little) faster iteration and does no need the `CStr` conversion. Not date format dependent, too:

```
Sub CentralizeDateLongValues()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngD As Range, lastCol As Long, lastColL As String
  Dim arrD1, arrD2, arrGen, minD As Date, maxD As Date, i As Long, j As Long
  Dim arrOddCols, arrCols, strCols As String, NoD As Long, mtch, col As Long, StartTime As Date
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set sh1 = sh.Next 'use here the sheet you need (where to return the processed range)
  
  lastR = sh.UsedRange.rows.Count                                        'last row
  lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'last column
  'extract the odd columns number in an array:
  arrOddCols = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & lastCol / 2 & ")*2-1)")
  Debug.Print Join(arrOddCols, "|"):     'just to visually check it. Comment the line after understanding what the above line does

  'obtain the columns letters array:
  ReDim arrCols(1 To UBound(arrOddCols))
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrOddCols)
        arrCols(i) = Split(cells(1, arrOddCols(i)).Address, "$")(1)
    Next i
  strCols = Join(arrCols, "1,") & "1": Debug.Print strCols        'just to visually check it.
  Set rngD = Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Range(strCols).EntireColumn) ' build the range where to match max/min dates
  
 minD = WorksheetFunction.min(rngD)
 maxD = WorksheetFunction.Max(rngD)
 NoD = maxD - minD + 1 'number the days in the range betweenthe min and max dates
   'build a continuous date array from long numbers, corespondent to min and max dates:
  arrD1 = Evaluate("row(" & CLng(minD) & ":" & CLng(maxD) & ")")
  'Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arrD1), "|"): 'Stop

 arrD2 = arrD1   ''clone the built dates arary
 ReDim Preserve arrD2(1 To UBound(arrD1), 1 To UBound(arrCols) + 1) 'add the necessary columns for Values
 
 StartTime = Timer 'start the timer to count the time spent by the following code.
 
 arrGen = sh.Range("A2", sh.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value2: col = 1
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrGen)
     For j = 1 To UBound(arrGen, 2) - 1 Step 2 'iterate from two to two columns to check dates (as string) and extract values
        If arrGen(i, j) <> "" Then
            col = col + 1
            mtch = Application.match(arrGen(i, j), arrD1, True)
            If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
                arrD2(mtch, col) = arrGen(i, j + 1)
            Else
               arrD2(mtch, col) = "strange..." 'the code reaches this line only if a mistake is in the Dates range...
            End If
        End If
     Next j
     col = 1 'reinitialize the variable to set the column where the value to be placed
 Next i
  'drop the processed array content at once
 Dim rngBlank As Range
 With sh1.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrD2), UBound(arrD2, 2))
    .Value2 = arrD2
    .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
    .BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
    On Error Resume Next 'for the case (even imporbable) that no any blank cell will exist...
     Set rngBlank = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
 End With
 If Not rngBlank Is Nothing Then rngBlank.Value = 0
 'put headers:
 Dim arrHd: arrHd = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arrD2, 2) - 1 & ")"))
 arrHd = Split("Date|Value" & Join(arrHd, "|Value"), "|")
 With sh1.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrHd) + 1)
    .Value = arrHd
    .Font.Bold = True
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
    .BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
 End With
 sh1.Activate
 MsgBox "Ready..." & vbCrLf & _
             " (" & Format(Timer - StartTime, "00.00") & " seconds)"
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it...

Comment: Hello @FaneDure, second example it's great, works perfectly. Much appreciated

Comment: @Vince Glad I could help! But how many seconds does it take for your working range (x rows and y series...)? The code should be fast, working only in memory, but **how fast**?

Comment: @FaneGuru, i've tested with lttle data, let me test it later with big data and i'll write you back with elapsed time. Many thanks again

Comment: Hello @Faneduru. The second sub it's pretty fast!! around 16 sec. is it posible to set no matching days to zero instead blank?

Comment: @Vince Everything can be done, if the theme is clear, but the algorithm will be much more complicated. I will process the returned range instead, in a very fast way, replacing blank with `0`. I will do it in a minute. I have the idea in my head...

Comment: @Vince Please, test the updated code which (finally) will return a range with zero instead of blank. I did not adapt the first version, since you like more the second one... I did not delete it, only to make somebody else (maybe you, too) seeing the code in the future, learning some ways of dealing with arrays (create in memory, make strings/ranges from them, match their elements, ReDim Preserve, clone, fill in a rapid way etc.). I like very much dealing with arrays and obtaining, using them, fast solution to deal with.

Comment: @Vince I also played with a little formatting (columns autofit, borders, bolded header, border around etc.)...

Comment: Wow, many thanks for the effort @FaneDuru, it works fantastic. I have learned a lot from your approach. Best